# why am I getting "invalid redirect_url" error message in OAuth 2.0 Authentication?

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, oauth-2.0

When I am working to get access token from a companies api I am getting "invalid redirect_url" error message.
I set this redirect_url in companies api. I also tested this url and method with swagger. Url is working true.

My access_token request like this:

```
string serviceUrl = $"https://apis.blabla.com/auth/oauth/v2/token?client_id={apiKey}&client_secret={apiSecret}&grant_type=client_credentials&redirect_uri={redirectUri}";
```

My redirect url is public and like this:

```
string redirectUri = "http://asd.zxc.com:1234/Api/GenerateToken/GenerateAccessToken"
```

GenerateToken is controller and GenerateAccessToken is method name. Method type is Post(as documantation wanted). Request model is same in documantation.
What could be the problem?

**-Edit**

Can GenerateAccessToken method be Void? Do I have to return something from redirect_url?

Comment: Does it need to be http**s** ?

Comment: My url is not https. I don't know. Is Https required in Oauth2 redirectUrl?

Comment: _"Is Https required in Oauth2 redirectUrl?"_ That was supposed to be my question. Does it?

Comment: I really don't know. It doesn't say anything like that in the documentation.

Comment: Can you make it https and try? I have a gut-feeling. But I don't know for sure, neither.

Comment: You can not use any redirect URI you like with OAuth, you have to register the redirect URI to the client you are using. You can probably do that whereever you got your client ID and secret from. https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/redirect-uri-registration/

Comment: @fbede I know and I did it. My problem is not that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. My method in redirect url take a request model. I created a model for that like in documentation. I changed this method. I am taking request as Object type and return same model in redirect url. Then this error resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I would double check that the redirect_uri in your `/oauth` request URL matches *exactly* that which is referenced in your oauth configuration/company settings. Even the smallest difference like http vs https or including wwww., etc. can throw an error. You might find some of the tips in this [OAuth Troubleshooting Guide](https://developers.miro.com/docs/troubleshooting-oauth20) that Miro made helpful for other common OAuth errors to check, too!

The first item in that guide covers `invalid redirect` errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the log file, there can be a clue. Logging is switched on in Program.cs. Beware the log files can get huge when debug level or info level is used.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Title = "IdentityServer";

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication", LogEventLevel.Information)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.File("logs\\my-identity-server.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
        .CreateLogger();

    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}
```